# how do I get stable connection of WiFi on my Samsung tablet A

Tags: wi-fi

My Samsung tablet A, gets disconnected immediately after connecting to router WiFi at my home. But at my office I do not face this problem with the router over there. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if your router is wireless n and if there is a switch to change it to wireless g. Try to change channel in router also.